# Show that there exists a bijection between $\mathbb{N^N}$ and $2^\mathbb N$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I have see somewhere that ${\aleph_0}^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$.That means that $|\mathbb{N^N}|=|2^\mathbb N|$.I want to show explicitly that there exists a bijection between $\mathbb {N^N}$ and $2^\mathbb N$ where $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$ denotes the set of all functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ and $2^\mathbb N$ denotes the power set of $\mathbb N$.I do not know how to start with.Any hint will be helpful.

Comment: *Hint.* You can write each integer in unary and separate them with zeroes.

Comment: Rather thank thinking of $2^\mathbb{N}$ as being the powerset of $\mathbb{N},$ it may be just more helpful for you to think of it as the set of all functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0,1\}.$ Hence, you are comparing a set of functions to another set of functions, and this should make envisioning possible bijections easier.